# Array.map not returning a value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

This is an api endpoint in nextJS that returns the respective authors for an array of posts. The posts is an array of objects that contains a key "authorId". The following code does not work.

```
const users = posts.map(async (post) => await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { id: post.authorId }}));
```

So, I tried the old school way. This thing works

```
    const users = []
    for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: posts[i].authorId,
                },
            });
            users.push(user);
        }
```

I thought that the arrow syntax or the implicit return is the issue. So, I tried like this:

```
        const getUsers = async (post: Post) => {
            const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: post.authorId,
                },
            });
            console.log(user);
            return user;
        };
        const users = posts.map(getUsers);
```

The user object is being logged to the console but its not returning the value (the users is an array of empty objects of times the size of the posts array). Can anyone say where I am doing it wrong?

> Note that I'm using prisma as an ORM

Comment: "array of empty objects" — It should be an array of promises, not empty objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your two code fragments are not equivalent.

`getUsers` is an async function, so it returns a Promise, that resolves with a user. So, in your last example, the `users` variable contain an array of promises. What you probably want to do is:

```
const users = await Promise.all(posts.map(getUsers));
```

To concurrently get all users from the array of promises.